# error [ERROR] OperationalError: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXXXXXX", user "XXXXX", database "XXXXXXX", no encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm facing this error in an aws lambda function: error
`[ERROR] OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXXXXXX", user "XXXXX", database "XXXXXXX", no encryption`

I'm already config the VPC access and the security groups and import the psycopg2 as a layer of the function.

here's the main code:

```
import psycopg2
import json
from linestring import create_line_string
import os

 
#except Exception as e:
#    print(e)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    db_host =  os.environ['DB_HOST']
    db_name = os.environ['DB_NAME']
    db_user = os.environ['USER_NAME']
    db_password = os.environ['PASSWORD']
    
    print('olá')
    #try :
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=db_host, dbname=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_password)
    cursor = conn.cursor()  

    # Extrair os dados do JSON da requisição
    user_id = event['user']
    occurrence_datetime = event['datetime']
    geolocation_data = create_line_string(event['data'])
    print(geolocation_data)
    # Conectar ao banco de dados RDS
    try:
        
        # Inserir os dados na tabela
        print('iniciando inserção')
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO geolocation (user_id, occurrence_datetime, geolocation_data) VALUES(%s, %s, %s);""", (user_id, occurrence_datetime, geolocation_data))
        print('query executando')
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

Comment: Can you also add your pg_hba.conf file above question?

Comment: Are you connecting to an Amazon RDS database (if so, use SSL) or are you connecting to a database that you installed on an Amazon EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem just changing the language to NodeJs and using the 'pg' module, in order to prove that the database is working, but there are some problem with the psycopg2. We need a new repository with working psycopg2 for aws lambda function.

Comment: I'm using RDS database